# Expanding Cell code not working correctly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

So i've been looking around for some code that will expand and contract my cells in my static TableView. I found a forum post where someone was attempting to do the same thing I am and borrowed some code.

I created a custom class based on a TableViewController. I added the following:

.h file

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;
```

.m file

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;

[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil
   && [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
    return 80;

return 40;
}
```

I use this as the viewController for my TableView.

It sort of work for expanding and contracting my tables but not really. It's really janky. It doesn't animate correctly and seems to be messing with the rows below the one I click.

How can I sort this out to animate and work correctly?

Also, when the view loads, how can I set the row height to a specified number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading the row that's selected, you should be using begin/end updates. This will allow the table to automatically make the necessary changes, and animate between them.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if ([indexPath compare:selectedCellIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        selectedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSIntegerMax inSection:0];
    }else{
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It doesn't reduce the cell size when clicked again though. Any way to sort that out?

Comment: Hi mate. Could you please be a bit more specific about adding an index checking condition? I'm trying to use this approach but am a bit stuck. Thanks